# Flutter create infinite screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I imagine a new kind of screen, and I would like to do it with Flutter since it's very powerful for rendering fast and smoothly.

I want to achieve a kind of infinite screen with kind of square or zone where you can move into. Actually exactly like a map (in fact not infinite but very large) but where I can:

- Drag and translate
- Zoom in and out
- Click and press on the different component of the screen (square or whatever)

I imagine use `GestureDetector` on my widget "map" combine with `transform` on each component insde and refresh the screen after each move, or redrawing each component with `draw` but I'm not sure it's the best way to follow with this.

Thanks for helping if you have any idea !!

Comment: Using [OverflowBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) is probably the way to go. Probably playing with the offset.padding of whatever is in that box, and use some sort of GridView to move around and rendering new tiles as you go. This is roughly following the "map" analogy.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented part of things you asked for except for the "infinite map".
The code is quite beefy so I've described this stuff in an [article on Medium](https://medium.com/@alexander.arendar/dragging-zooming-and-placing-object-on-indoor-map-with-flutter-67667ef415ec).
It allows:

- move map by dragging
- place new objects on the map
- zoom in/out
- click objects

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/AlexanderArendar/overflow).

Answer (score 3):

## The `InteractiveViewer` widget

One solution could be using the `InteractiveViewer` widget with its `constrained` property set to `false` as it will out of the box support:

- Drag and translate
- Zooming in and out - Simply set `minScale` and `maxScale`
- Clicking and pressing widgets like normal

`InteractiveViewer` as featured on *Flutter Widget of the Week*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg

### Infinite size

Regarding the question's infinite size part, a maximum size for the child widget must be specified, however this can be **very large**, so large that it is actually hard to re-find widgets in the center of the screen.

### Alignment of the child content

By default the child content will start from the top left, and panning will show content outside the screen. However, by providing a `TransformationController` the default position can be changed by providing a `Matrix4` object in the constructor, f.ex. the content can be center aligned if desired this way.

## Example code

The code contains an example widget that uses the InteractiveViewer to show an extremely large widget, the example centers the content.

```dart
class InteractiveViewerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const InteractiveViewerExample({
    Key? key,
    required this.viewerSize,
    required this.screenHeight,
    required this.screenWidth,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double viewerSize;
  final double screenHeight;
  final double screenWidth;

  @override
  State<InteractiveViewerExample> createState() =>
      _InteractiveViewerExampleState();
}

class _InteractiveViewerExampleState extends State<InteractiveViewerExample> {
  late TransformationController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: InteractiveViewer.builder(
          boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          minScale: 0.001,
          maxScale: 50,
          transformationController: controller,
          builder: (BuildContext context, vector.Quad quad) {
            return Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: widget.viewerSize,
                height: widget.viewerSize,
                child: const InteractiveViewerContent(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initiate the transformation controller with a centered position.
    // If you want the InteractiveViewer TopLeft aligned remove the
    // TransformationController code, as the default controller in
    // InteractiveViewer does that.
    controller = TransformationController(
      Matrix4.translation(
        vector.Vector3(
          (-widget.viewerSize + widget.screenWidth) / 2,
          (-widget.viewerSize + widget.screenHeight) / 2,
          0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Example content; some centered and top left aligned widgets,
// and a gradient background.
class InteractiveViewerContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const InteractiveViewerContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle? style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6;

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: <Color>[Colors.orange, Colors.red, Colors.yellowAccent],
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: SelectableText("Top Left", style: style),
          ),
          SelectableText("Center", style: style),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Usage

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: InteractiveViewerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class InteractiveViewerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const InteractiveViewerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: InteractiveViewerExample(
          viewerSize: 50000,
          screenHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          screenWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### What does the code do

[image: InteractiveViewer in action]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting proposal. I don't have the implementation, after all, it's up to you but I have some pointers.

Translation, I imagine, can easily be handled by 2 nested ListViews. One, that scrolls X and one that scrolls in Y direction. `ScrollController` can be queries for all kinds of info.

Zoom is also fairly easy at first blick: you can wrap the entire screen in a `Transform.scale()` widget.

You could wrap each `tappable` widget in a `GuestureDetector`, query for their `RenderBox` to get their position on screen in local or global coordinates, get their size.

Note: in games, there is a concept called clipping distance. Figuring out how to implement that in Flutter is going to be a fun challenge. It allows you not to render those Widgets that are too small, you zoomed out a lot eg. Let me know how it goes! Curious.

---