# How to repaint the GridPaper to fill the screen when pan or zoom the InteractiveViewer in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make an infinite canvas with flutter and plan to put nodes and graphs on it. (Just like draw.io).

I'm currently working on the first step of drawing a grid background. I've found GridPaper and InteractiveViewer widgets to draw the background. But when I zoom or pan the grid, it isn't redrawing itself (extend the grid with zoom or pan action).

I've read the answers to similar questions, [Flutter create infinite screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935470/flutter-create-infinite-screen) and [How to create an infinite grid in Flutter with InteractiveViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291286/how-to-create-an-infinite-grid-in-flutter-with-interactiveviewer).

So, what can I do with CustomPaint or TransformationController to extend the grid to fill the screen while keeping the zoom level? You know, it is similar kind of functionality we saw on draw.io.

Here is the code I have now:

infinite_canvas.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:aimed_infinite_canvas/src/presentation/widget/background.dart';

class InfiniteCanvas extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InfiniteCanvas({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _InfiniteCanvasState();
}

class _InfiniteCanvasState extends ConsumerState<InfiniteCanvas> {
  ValueNotifier<double> _valueNotifier = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return InteractiveViewer(
            boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
            onInteractionStart: (details) {},
            onInteractionUpdate: (details) {},
            onInteractionEnd: (details) {},
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: BackgroundPainter(valueNotifier: _valueNotifier),
              child: const SizedBox.expand(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Background(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ValueNotifier<double> valueNotifier;

  BackgroundPainter({required this.valueNotifier})
      : super(repaint: valueNotifier) {}

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

background.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class Background extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Background({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _BackgroundState();
}

class _BackgroundState extends ConsumerState<Background> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridPaper(
      divisions: 2,
      subdivisions: 2,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was considering increasing the size of the grid dynamically, but a large fixed size should work too. I'm gonna stick with your approach for now. Thank you very much.

Comment: size of grid dynamically? what you mean?

Comment: SizedBox.expand can fill the screen, right? With the expand, I don't need to specify the size of the grid, so I was thinking something like repainting the screen when I zoom out and SizedBox.expand refill the screen. But I do think your way is great, a fixed size is sufficient enough for this functionality.

Comment: I tried instead of `SizedBox` with fixed huge size (like 1000000 in my case) to use `double.infinity` but it doesn't work

Comment: double.infinity won't work I guess. It's not a fixed size with constrained: false, the grid won't know what size to draw. That's the reason why I use SizedBox.expand. I assume SizedBox.expand reads the screen size.